# Hibernate entity id generation requires a database hit

Tags: hibernate

entityManager.persist(employee)

when we call this, then does Hibernate goes to database to generate identity for employee entity, or its generated at hibernate side only?

Comment: Can you please post entity code? It depends how is entity defined.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it depends on your Id generation strategy. If you entity's id is Auto Increment(`GenerationType.IDENTITY`), then there is no need for additional database hit. But if you are using sequences (`GenerationType.SEQUENCE`), then hibernate hits database. But you can tweak it using `@SequenceGenerator` annotation. There is an attribute `allocationSize` which indicates the amount for increment by when allocating sequence numbers from the sequence. This reduces the database hits since you allocate more Id values in a single hit.

Also, you can check database hits using some profiling tools like [Xrebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/xrebel/) which shows both JPA and SQL queries.